# Correct way to request publications

Tags: graphql, shopify

So I am currently trying to get all publication channels I can publish products at and am a bit confused...

The `channels` query is depricated: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2023-07/queries/channels

The `publications` query should be fine as of the documentation: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2023-07/queries/publications 
But if I exec the query, i get a deprication error:

```
// Query:
  const sessions = await sessionStorage.findSessionsByShop(shop);
  const offline = sessions.find(s => !s.isOnline);
  if (offline) {
    const client = new shopifyAPP.clients.Graphql({
      session,
      apiVersion: LATEST_API_VERSION,
    });
    const result = await client.query({ 
      data: `
        query publications {
          publications(first: 10) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `
    });
  }

// Error:
{
  message:"https://shopify.dev/api/usage/versioning#deprecation-practices",
  path:"https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-07/graphql.json",
  body: {
    query:"
      query publications {          
        publications(first: 10) {
          ...
        }
      }
    "
  }
}
```

So what is the correct way to query the publication channel? 
Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think its endpoint related issue,

You need to update your endpoint details

```js
// You are using old one
https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-07/graphql.json
//                                              ^ HERE update this [2023-10]

// You can use this new endpoint
https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-10/graphql.json
```

### Answer Revised

Seems there is a minor correction

```js
//      HERE { (bracket) and ` (backtick)  \/  wrong order. put bracket inside
const result = await client.query({ data: { ` 
  query publications { // <- Remove this
    publications(first: 10) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    } 
  } // <- Remove this
    `} });
// ^^^ HERE put bracket inside
```

> **HERE the bracket is supposed to be inside of the backtick (`) sign**

```js
// correction
const result = await client.query({ 
  data: `{
    publications(first: 10) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }`
});
```

ref: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql

if any doubt please comment

Comment: But the documentation of `2023-07` and  `2023-10` state that this method is NOT deprecated XD

Comment: you may be right but try to update the month and check, here with 10th version publications are working fine, for me it seems it also works fine with 07th 

Comment: hmm can you share how you are calling that GQL bit of code may be there is some issue, i guess

Comment: Updated my example. But also in the latest shopifyAPI version `LATEST_API_VERSION` is still `ApiVersion.July23` alias `2023-07`. still the same problem.

Comment: hmm is it possible for you to show how you are making requests? as this depreciation message should not come.

Comment: Like I said. I updated the question and added the entire code.

Comment: ok ok, I just oversaw that one, I added a revised answer seems there is one mistake in writing the code.. please check the revised answer for correction

Comment: This is not a mistake but naming. In Graphql you can name your queries, wich actualy is advised: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/operation-best-practices/
Also this is not the problem since this will trigger the problem as well.

Comment: yes you can name it but make sure you put that first curly bracket for data inside the backtick, means all your gql string/definition make sure it's like data: 'here' no outside curly bracket

Comment: naming is fine, but check backtick and bracket thing to correct your code 

Comment: Backticks are just JS templating strings and have nothing to do with the query itself. Also the brackets do not matter since I am naming the query. Sadly this answer does not provide any useful information.

Comment: Sir, have you tried using my revised answer code? Its just you need to put that bracket inside backtick that is it

Comment: Jea this was a typo I forgot to remove the brackets... Still the problem with the deprication warning persists.

Comment: Once please replace your whole client. query code with mine from the solution and it should work, as from your updated question I think that shopify do not like that `query publications`, just try it once 

Comment: I did. I realy did. It does not change the problem XD

Comment: hmm ok let's do google meet if its okay , strange issue 